# Can't get MapKit to work

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Im following a tutorial on how to work with MapKit and I am having trouble getting past the first few steps of the tutorial. I have checked other tutorials and they all have the exact same initial steps.

1. I place a Map Kit View onto my view controller.
2. I add: import MapKit.
3. I add the MapKit framework to my project.
4. I add an outlet to my view controller.

But I get a warning that ViewController is part of module Mapkit and ignoring MapKit

And then I get an error: use of undeclared type MKMapView - which is most likely caused by MapKit not being imported.

Here's a screen shot of the errors and the code:

[image]

I believe I am following the tutorial steps correctly.

Any idea whats Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess here is that you called your application `MapKit` and you are seeing a collision with the actual MapKit framework because the modules have the same name.

Either:

- create a new project

or

- adjust the module name build setting (Product Build Name) to avoid a conflict.

Comment: yep - this was it - I had just realised this myself and came back here to update my post and saw that you had already posted the correct answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Apart of the weak reference and the syntax issues I would suggest you to check your Project name - the name might clashes with the iOS library! 
This issue happened to me in the past - check this out
If it doesn't work for you let me know

Answer (score 0):

1. Restart Xcode
2. Clean the code
3. Add MpKit framework.